# Running method on every call using express-graphql

Tags: express, graphql, express-graphql

I'm using [express-graqphl](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql) and was wondering if there is any concept of running a function before each graphql endpoint is executed? I'd like to have this for things like validating JWTs and other things. I realize we could use express for this, e.g.

```
app.use('/graphql`, doChecks);
```

but I'd like for the graphql handler to throw an error so it'll be inside the `errors: []` list in the results giving the client a consistent experience with the api. Is there any direct support for this in the package?

Answer (score 0):

The `context` function is executed before every request. If you're using Apollo v4+ then here are the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/context/#the-context-function)

The context function is most often used to manage auth, including reading and validation of security tokens.